# Extract weather values from app.weathercloud.net

Tags: html, google-sheets, xpath, extract, unique-values

Hi all I would like to extract 25.8 value from this html block using xpath
the html code is from a weather website, https://app.weathercloud.net/

```
"<div id=""gauge-rainrate""><h3>Intensidad de lluvia</h3><canvas id=""rainrate"" width=""200"" height=""200""></canvas><div class=""summary"">
        <table>
                <tbody><tr>
                        <th> mm/h</th>
                        <th class=""max""><i class=""icon-chevron-up icon-white""></i>&nbsp; Máx&nbsp;</th>
                </tr>                
                <tr>
                        <td class=""grey"">Diaria</td>
                        <td><a id=""gauge-rainrate-max-day"" rel=""tooltip"" title="""" data-original-title=""22/04/2022 00:00"">0.0</a></td>
                </tr>                
                <tr>
                        <td class=""grey"">Mensual</td>
                        <td><a id=""gauge-rainrate-max-month"" rel=""tooltip"" title=""21/04/2022 02:15"">25.8</a></td>
                </tr>                
                <tr>
                        <td class=""grey"">Anual</td>
                        <td><a id=""gauge-rainrate-max-year"" rel=""tooltip"" title=""21/04/2022 02:15"">25.8</a></td>
                </tr>
        </tbody></table>
</div></div>"
```

I use this expression to extract in a google spreadsheet cell

```
=IMPORTXML("https://app.weathercloud.net/d5044837546#current";"//a[@id='gauge-rainrate-max-month']")
```

apparently the code is correct but my output is always

```
-
```

I don't understand why...

Comment: the html looks invalid, there are duplicated double quotes `""gauge-rainrate-max-month""`

Comment: if you disable JS there is no value. import formula of GS do not support javascript scrapping